# Can a batch task read files on a file share?

Tags: python, azure-batch

I have a file share with (you guessed it) a lot of files. I want to create a batch job which mounts this file share and the reads in each of the files and processes each one in parallel  (each as a batch task).

Is this possible to do with python and in azure batch? Any tutorial showing how to do this would be great.

Comment: Can you clarify if you are attempting to mount Azure File shares and which operating system/platform?

Comment: The OS will be ubuntu and yes, the VM/ node created by azure batch would need to mount the file share.

Comment: By Azure File shares I mean [Azure File Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/files/) proper. Are you mounting this?

Comment: Yes, file share, not blob storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in one of two ways. Note that the following only applies to Linux. Windows users will need to follow a slightly different method using [User Identities](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.batch.models.html#azure.batch.models.UserIdentity).

1. Mount the file share at the compute node level using the pool's [StartTask](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.batch.models.html#azure.batch.models.StartTask) object. Please see the [Azure File documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) on how to do this for your distro on Linux. The start task can either:

   - Mount the file share directly, i.e., call `mount -t cifs ...`. This will work through reboots as the StartTask is re-run everytime on reboot.
   - Modify `/etc/fstab` to add an entry to automount. Note that you must make this operation idempotent as the StartTask is re-run everytime on reboot.
2. Mount the file share at the job level using the job's [JobPreparationTask](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.batch.models.html#azure.batch.models.JobPreparationTask) object. The command you specify here will only run once for every task under the job. You should probably also specify the job's [JobReleaseTask](http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.batch.models.html#azure.batch.models.JobReleaseTask) to `unmount` the share for cleanup.

Make sure, in any path you choose, that proper elevation privileges are given to the task (typically superuser) such that the process can perform the mount or modify `/etc/fstab`.

If you go with the first option, the mount will be available all the time to the compute node regardless if a job that requires it or not is run on that node. There are advantages and disadvantages for each approach. Your requirements, be it compliance, or technical (for example) should help you on which to choose.

Comment: Great, so where would the File Share be mounted? For example, if I used the linux command and told it to mount to `/home/mounts/data`, would the FS be mounted in `data`?

Comment: The Batch compute node does not alter/intercept the mount command. It is run on the system as if you were giving it interactively. As long as the destination directory exists (if it does not, you need to `mkdir` it first prior to mounting), the mount should work. You should investigate mounting to a [known compute node location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-compute-node-environment-variables#command-line-expansion-of-environment-variables) (e.g., `$AZ_BATCH_NODE_SHARED_DIR/data`) which may help with your tasks instead of hardcoding locations.

Comment: Thank you, using `$AZ_BATCH_NODE_SHARED_DIR` is a good idea. I will give that a try.

Comment: Just a note: if you're going the `/etc/fstab` route, the `$AZ_BATCH_NODE_SHARED_DIR` variable won't be available as those mounts happen outside of an Azure Batch task context. These environment variables are only available when a process executes a shell within an Azure Batch task context (all tasks, including StartTask and JobPrep/JobRelease will have these env vars set).

Comment: Thanks, I'm going the first route. Reading/writing from/to files is proving tricky as I have no idea where that EV points to. Think I'll create a user, log in and dump it to console.